# Graphalgorithm execution in Graphdatabases

Tags: nosql, neo4j, allegrograph

Where are the graphalgorithms like traversals or shortest-path executed using a graphdatabase? Are they executed on the database-server itself or are they executed on the clientside? In the latter case it seems to be necessary to send request to the server for every iterationstep.

Noe4j provides algorithms for traversal and shortest path. Does any other graph database provides additionally a max flow algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

normally, the graph algos in Neo4j are executed on the server side. Shuffling all edges over the network would be too time consuming. You can do this by scritping on the server side, like the Max-Flow algo example at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/gremlin-plugin.html#rest-api-flow-algorithms-with-gremlin or use existing ones via e.g. Cypher, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-match.html#match-shortest-path

HTH

/peter